# nginx location with proxy server

Tags: nginx, proxy, centos, location, flv

Got nginx proxy server setup ready. The server handles requests from main machine.
The following configuration is working for common files, but flv returns 404 not found error:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:80/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;

        location ~* \.flv$ {
        flv;
        root /var/www/machinery/data/www;
        }
  }
```

Basically i want .flv pseudo-streaming handled by the server. It seems nginx is trying to find a flv file inside the proxy server(according to logs), not in the main server where file is located.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question would actually be: Can someone use NGinx to do pseudo streaming for proxied FLV files?

And the answer is no, you cannot.

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same result. I placed internal location block just after the main, though server is trying to find flv files inside itself.

Comment: What do you mean inside itself? Where are your FLVs actually? If your FLV files are on the "http://x.x.x.x:80/" server, then this thing you are doing cannot work. The FLV directive only works with local files afaik.

Comment: I mean it is not referring to flv files on the main server, looking for local files only. I see, it looks like pseudo streaming with flv would not work for proxying server with nginx. Am i right?